# Need help to "translate" this C code into only if sentences one

Tags: c

When I try to change main while loop into an if I get a segmentation fault error, it works perfectly with that 1 while but I need it if fully-built. It is a program to calculate how many combinations of different numbers can be found according to the n number that is given in the main function.

I would really appreciate if anyone can change that while loop to if without changing "that much" the code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ft_print_combn(int n);
int limite(int, int, int, int);
void subft_print_combn(int, int, int, int);
int sub2ft_print_combn(int, int);
void impceros(int, int);
void imprimir(int, int);
unsigned char finciclos(int, int, int);

int main(){
ft_print_combn(5);
}

void ft_print_combn(int n){
  subft_print_combn(n, 1, 0, limite(10, 10, n, n));
}

int limite(int n, int tope, int tope1, int exponente){
if(exponente>1){
    tope=tope*n;
    limite(n, tope, tope1, exponente=exponente-1);
}
else
    return tope;
}

void subft_print_combn(int n, int cc, int x, int lim){
while(cc<lim){
    int csc = cc;
    int condimp=1;
    condimp=sub2ft_print_combn(csc, condimp);
    if(condimp==1) {
        impceros(cc, lim);
        imprimir(cc, n);
        if(finciclos(cc, n, 0)==0) 
            printf("%c", ' ');
    }
    cc=cc+1;
}
}

int sub2ft_print_combn(int csc, int condimp){
if(csc >= 10){
    if(csc%10<=(csc/10)%10){
        condimp=0;
    }
    sub2ft_print_combn(csc=csc/10, condimp);
}
else
    return condimp;
}

void impceros(int n, int lim){
if(n*10<lim){
    printf("%c", '0');
    impceros(n=n*10, lim);
}
}


void imprimir(int n2, int n){
if (n2 < 10){
    printf("%c", n2 + '0');
}
else 
    if (n2 >= 10){
        imprimir(n2/10, n);
        printf("%c", n2%10 + '0');
    }
}

unsigned char finciclos(int n, int e, int res){
if((e==1 && n==9)||(e==2&&n==89)||(e==3&&n==789)||(e==4&&n==6789)||(e==5&&n==56789)|| 
(e==6&&n==456789)||(e==7&&n==3456789)||(e==8&&n==23456789)||(e==9&&n==123456789))
    res=1;
else 
    res=0;
return res;
}
```

This is the code with the error... In other words, the code with my idea of how to change the while loop into if.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void ft_print_combn(int n);
 int limite(int, int, int, int);
 void subft_print_combn(int, int, int, int, int, int);
 void sub2ft_print_comb (int, int, int);
 void impceros(int, int);
 void imprimir(int, int);
 unsigned char finciclos(int, int, int);

 int main(){
    ft_print_combn(5);
 }

 void ft_print_combn(int n){
  subft_print_combn(n, 1, 1, 0, limite(10, 10, n, n), 1);
  }

 void subft_print_combn(int n, int cc, int csc, int x, int lim, int condimp){
  if(cc<lim){
    condimp=sub2ft_print_combn(csc, condimp);
    if(condimp==1)
        sub2ft_print_comb(n, cc, lim);
    cc=cc+1;
    subft_print_combn(n, cc, cc, x, lim, 1);
}
}

void sub2ft_print_comb (int n, int cc, int lim){
impceros(cc, lim);
imprimir(cc, n);
if(finciclos(cc, n, 0)==0) 
    printf("%c", ' ');
}

int limite(int n, int tope, int tope1, int exponente){
if(exponente>1){
    tope=tope*n;
    limite(n, tope, tope1, exponente=exponente-1);
}
else
    return tope;
}


int sub2ft_print_combn(int csc, int condimp){
if(csc >= 10){
    if(csc%10<=(csc/10)%10){
        condimp=0;
    }
    sub2ft_print_combn(csc=csc/10, condimp);
}
else
    return condimp;
}

void impceros(int n, int lim){
if(n*10<lim){
    printf("%c", '0');
    impceros(n=n*10, lim);
}
}


void imprimir(int n2, int n){
if (n2 < 10){
    printf("%c", n2 + '0');
}
else 
    if (n2 >= 10){
        imprimir(n2/10, n);
        printf("%c", n2%10 + '0');
    }
}

unsigned char finciclos(int n, int e, int res){
if((e==1 && n==9)||(e==2&&n==89)||(e==3&&n==789)||(e==4&&n==6789)|| 
(e==5&&n==56789)||(e==6&&n==456789)||(e==7&&n==3456789)|| 
(e==8&&n==23456789)||(e==9&&n==123456789))
    res=1;
else 
    res=0;
return res;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for help rewriting the while loop as recursion or something else? Also, note that when you do do recursion (in `limite` and `sub2ft_print_combn`) you are not returning the value, which your compiler will warn you about.

Comment: Yes, I changed the while loop to if but for some reason I keep getting a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" error....However, if i leave the while loop instead, the program works correctly... Of course, when i change it to if I have in mind the recursive call of the function and that stuff...  And unfortunately I need only if´s.

Comment: *"I keep getting a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)""* - always consider that situation as a mandate to run your program in a debugger.

Comment: The thing is: the program works fine only with if´s as long as I put as n number 1,2,3 or 4... If put 5, 6, 7 or 9(the max) it works fine until the combinations go to 26789.... If i debug my program i would have to go over 26789 cycles to finally get to the error point...

Comment: You don't need to step through each line in the debugger, you can just run it until it hits the segmentation fault. Please post the version of the code that triggers the segmentation fault, instead of us making us guess how you're making it recursive. (Also, as noted above, your other recursive functions are almost certainly wrong).

Comment: Updated. Those are both versions... With while loop and if´s.... No big changes and not matter it´s the same, I keep getting the error only when i change the while into if

Comment: If I fix the undefined return values in all your recursive functions, both versions of your program run without errors for me and produce the same output.

Comment: Could you please guide me, tell me what to change-do or share with me the code with the parts you changed? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the only issue, but you should be getting compiler warnings because your recursive functions do not always set the return value. `e.g. program.c:25:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` (Note that there is another compiler warning about the implicit declaration of a function which should probably be addressed, but I don't think that's directly causing issues here.)

If I fix that (by adding `return` in the conditional that does the recursion), both versions of your program run without errors and have the same output:

```
int limite(int n, int tope, int tope1, int exponente){
if(exponente>1){
    tope=tope*n;
    return limite(n, tope, tope1, exponente=exponente-1); // Return this, don't just call it
}
else
    return tope;
}

int sub2ft_print_combn(int csc, int condimp){
if(csc >= 10){
    if(csc%10<=(csc/10)%10){
        condimp=0;
    }
    return sub2ft_print_combn(csc=csc/10, condimp); // Return this, don't just call it
}
else
    return condimp;
}
```

Explanation:

Section 6.9.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the
> function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So in a simple, non-recursive case

```
int myfunc(int a) {
 if (a>0) {
  int b = 10;
 }
 else {
  return 0;
 }
}
```

if I call `myfunc(0)` this will definitely return 0, but if I call `myfunc(1)` it never hits a return statement so the value returned is undefined.

The same thing applies to a recursive function.

```
int myfunc(int a) {
 if (a > 0) {
  myfunc(a-1);
 }
 else {
  return 0;
 }
}
```

If I call this with as `int ret = myfunc(1)` the stack will look something like

> 3: myfunc(0) -> return 0
>
> 2: myfunc(1) -> calls myfunc(0) but reaches end of function before
> hitting a return
>
> 1: main -> calls myfunc(1) but gets undefined result

I hope that clarifies it a bit. Note that in more complicated recursive functions, you wouldn't want it to automatically return a value from the first recursion, since you might need to do other operations first.

```
int myfunc(int a) {
 if (a > 100) {
  return a;
 }
 else {
  int b = myfunc(a+1) + myfunc(a+2) + myfunc(a+3);
  b *= myfunc(a+100);
  return b * myfunc(a+5);
 }
}
```

This is silly example, but I clearly don't want the value of one of those recursive calls automatically returned since I operate on the values afterward.

Comment: Wow.... Thank you so much!... I use Dev C++ and an online compiler: GDB... None of them said anything related about it... Which compiler do you use?. Also, if it wasn't for you I would never have thought on putting a return on those functions, it would be so helpful for me if you can give me a little explanation about why doing that and not just calling the function knowing that i was returning the variable anyways.... Actually, by just returning those variables the program did work partially.... Beyond that, I really appreciate your help, Thank you!

Comment: I've added some more explanation to my answer (I hope it makes sense). I use Clang, but I would have expected most compilers to show that warning.

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering... Do you may know how to solve the same problem but with numbers n 6, 7, 8 and 9? When i put in the main function those numbers i keep getting the segmentation fault error but ONLY in the if´s fully-built one

Comment: When you run it with 7, the limite function returns 10000000. This means your sub2ft_print_combn adds itself to the stack 10000000-7 times before it starts returning (which is much too big for the stack on typical computers causing your error). It's not realistic to put that much on the stack. (My computer errors out after sub2ft_print_combn is on the stack 209598 times). Finding a way to keep it recursive while reducing the stack size might be possible, but it will never be as efficient as the while loop was.